# Why we can't use a compound index with two or more independent range conditions?

Tags: sql, database

[use-the-index-luke.com](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/index-merge-performance) says:

> Nevertheless there are queries where a single index cannot do a
>   perfect job, no matter how you define the index; e.g., queries with
>   two or more independent range conditions as in the following example:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, date_of_birth 
FROM employees 
WHERE UPPER(last_name) < ?
   AND date_of_birth < ?
```

> It is impossible to define a B-tree index that would support this
>   query without filter predicates.

**I don't understand its explanation specially the last sentence. Can someone help?**

Comment: How would you define an index that can server both predicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't the explaination given there good enough?

> No matter how you twist and turn the index definition, the entries are always arranged along a chain. At one end, you have the small entries and at the other end the big ones. An index can therefore only support one range condition as an access predicate. Supporting two independent range conditions requires a second axis, for example like a chessboard. The query above would then match all entries from one corner of the chessboard, but an index is not like a chessboard—it is like a chain. There is no corner.

Comment: Is it possible to have one range condition and one equality condition both as access predicate? How?

Comment: @MajidAzimi Have you read the previous pages on Use The Index, Luke? E.g. this http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates